# Null Response in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am having a issue to get response by using **retrofit** library.
My JSON is below

```
{
  "regData": [
    {
      "registrationType": "User",
      "userDetails": {
        "city": "Bangalore ",
        "country": "Bangalore ",
        "email": "hfhg@lll.com",
        "name": "Cxhcc",
        "password": "123456",
        "phoneno": "486586"
      },
      "vehicleRegsiration": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Please note that above json i got after debug of my application and when i used same JSON with postman rest client application, it is working fine.

Below is my code

```
public void postRegistrationData(Registeration reqBody){
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<Long> call = apiService.registrationApi(reqBody);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Long> call, Response<Long> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Long id = response.body().longValue();
                Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + id);
            } else{
                Log.d(TAG, "Response failed: ");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Long>call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

After execution of above code its always executing below code

> Log.d(TAG, "Response failed: ");

```
public Registeration prepareRegRequestBody(UserDetails uDetail , VehicleRegsiration vDedail, String regType){
    RegDatum reg = new RegDatum();
    List<RegDatum> regList = new ArrayList<RegDatum>();
    Registeration regUV = new Registeration();
    reg.setRegistrationType(regType);
    reg.setUserDetails(uDetail);
    reg.setVehicleRegsiration(vDedail);
    regList.add(reg);
    regUV.setRegData(regList);
    return regUV;
}

public Registeration inputDataUV(){
    UserDetails userDetail = new UserDetails();
    VehicleRegsiration vehicleRegsiration = new VehicleRegsiration();
    Registeration reqbody = new Registeration();
    if(userType.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("User")){
        userDetail.setEmail(signupInputEmail.getText().toString());
        userDetail.setPassword(signupInputPassword.getText().toString());
        userDetail.setPhoneno(signupInputMobile.getText().toString());
        userDetail.setName(signupInputName.getText().toString());
        userDetail.setCountry(countryName1.getText().toString());
        userDetail.setCity(signupInputCity.getText().toString());
        reqbody = prepareRegRequestBody(userDetail, vehicleRegsiration, "User" );
        return reqbody;

    } else if(userType.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Vehicle")){
        vehicleRegsiration.setVehicleOwner(vSignupEmailId.getText().toString());
        vehicleRegsiration.setVehicleNoPlate(vSignupVnumber.getText().toString());
        vehicleRegsiration.setVehicleType(vSignupType.getText().toString());
        vehicleRegsiration.setImeiNo(Long.parseLong(vSignupImeiNo.getText().toString()));
        vehicleRegsiration.setPassword(vSignupPassword.getText().toString());
        vehicleRegsiration.setCountry(vcountryName1.getText().toString());
        vehicleRegsiration.setCity(vSignupCity.getText().toString());
        reqbody = prepareRegRequestBody(userDetail, vehicleRegsiration, "Vehicle" );
        return reqbody;
    } else{
        return reqbody;
    }
}
```

Where i am doing wrong please help me get rid of this issue.

Comment: Try debugging your code and check what `response` contains. Maybe it's a server error .

Comment: If it's server error then it should not work with Postman, but it is working fine with Postman.

Comment: I mean, 400 error or something like that...

Comment: why are you expecting a `Long` object, you could make a model class of your response and then use it instead

Comment: @Navneetヅ Why? Does retrofit will accept long as response.

Comment: @Héctor. Yours suggestion help ma a lot. There was  a unwanted slash in URL, i removed it and not able to post data in Server database but not able to get response. Request is going on server successfully but i am not able to collect the response.

Comment: Noe it always going in public void onFailure(Call<Long>call, Throwable t)